# Hiding URL parameter with Mod-Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies

I am not sure if this is possible.
I have the following url structure

```
http://www.my-domain.com/layouts/page.php?artist=artist-name&link=1234
```

which shows in the address bar as

```
http://www.my-domain.com/artists/artist-name/1234
```

In the .htaccesss file I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^artists/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /layouts/page.php?artist=$1&link=$2 [L]
```

What I would like is to hide the last variable (the 1234) from showing in the address bar but still be available to process on the target page. The address bar would show

```
http://www.my-domain.com/artists/artist-name
```

If this is not possible can I save the variable (the 1234) to a cookie from the .htaccess file then remove the variable so it isn't shown in the address bar? Then I can pick it up on the target page from the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `(.+)`. Something in this manner:

```
RewriteRule ^artists/artist-name/\d+-(.+) /artists/$1 [R=301]
```